# Split a Pandas column of lists into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, split

I have a Pandas DataFrame with one column:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"teams": [["SF", "NYG"] for _ in range(7)]})

       teams
0  [SF, NYG]
1  [SF, NYG]
2  [SF, NYG]
3  [SF, NYG]
4  [SF, NYG]
5  [SF, NYG]
6  [SF, NYG]
```

How can split this column of lists into two columns?

Desired result:

```
  team1 team2
0    SF   NYG
1    SF   NYG
2    SF   NYG
3    SF   NYG
4    SF   NYG
5    SF   NYG
6    SF   NYG
```

Answer (score 530, accepted):

You can use the `DataFrame` constructor with `lists` created by [`to_list`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html):

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'teams': [['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG'],
                ['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG']]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
print (df2)
       teams
0  [SF, NYG]
1  [SF, NYG]
2  [SF, NYG]
3  [SF, NYG]
4  [SF, NYG]
5  [SF, NYG]
6  [SF, NYG]
```

---

```
df2[['team1','team2']] = pd.DataFrame(df2.teams.tolist(), index= df2.index)
print (df2)
       teams team1 team2
0  [SF, NYG]    SF   NYG
1  [SF, NYG]    SF   NYG
2  [SF, NYG]    SF   NYG
3  [SF, NYG]    SF   NYG
4  [SF, NYG]    SF   NYG
5  [SF, NYG]    SF   NYG
6  [SF, NYG]    SF   NYG
```

And for a new `DataFrame`:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df2['teams'].to_list(), columns=['team1','team2'])
print (df3)
  team1 team2
0    SF   NYG
1    SF   NYG
2    SF   NYG
3    SF   NYG
4    SF   NYG
5    SF   NYG
6    SF   NYG
```

A solution with `apply(pd.Series)` is very slow:

```
#7k rows
df2 = pd.concat([df2]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [121]: %timeit df2['teams'].apply(pd.Series)
1.79 s ± 52.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [122]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(df2['teams'].to_list(), columns=['team1','team2'])
1.63 ms ± 54.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212915/discussion-between-amc-and-jezrael).

Comment: List method will reset index. If you want to keep index, copy index after construct df2 with `df1.index = d2.index`.

Comment: what about :
`df1.apply(lambda x: x["teams"], result_type="expand",axis=1) `

Comment: @RoyAssis - Can you test performance? I think it is slow

Comment: @jezrael Not that I think about it using apply is not performant. Ill check.

Comment: Seems like the "tolist" method only works when all lists are the same length.

Comment: Can I alert that this doesn't work for the general case where loading from, say a real csv, results in data the equivalent of `df = pd.DataFrame({"teams": [["SF, NYG"] for _ in range(7)]})`, nor also if the data has an unknown number of list items.

Answer (score 122):

Much simpler solution:

```
pd.DataFrame(df2["teams"].to_list(), columns=['team1', 'team2'])
```

Yields,

```
  team1 team2
-------------
0    SF   NYG
1    SF   NYG
2    SF   NYG
3    SF   NYG
4    SF   NYG
5    SF   NYG
6    SF   NYG
7    SF   NYG
```

If you wanted to split a column of delimited strings rather than lists, you could similarly do:

```
pd.DataFrame(df["teams"].str.split('<delim>', expand=True).values,
             columns=['team1', 'team2'])
```

Comment: what if each list has uneven number of elements?

Comment: _If you wanted to split a column of delimited strings rather than lists, you could similarly do:_ `df["teams"].str.split('<delim>', expand=True)` already returns a DataFrame, so it would probably be simpler to just rename the columns.

Comment: Thanks @AMC that did it for me, but as my "list" of UUID's was actually a `str` pretending to be a list, first I had to apply a lambda to remove square brackets.

Answer (score 77):

This solution preserves the index of the `df2` DataFrame, unlike any solution that uses `tolist()`:

```py
df3 = df2.teams.apply(pd.Series)
df3.columns = ['team1', 'team2']
```

Here's the result:

```
  team1 team2
0    SF   NYG
1    SF   NYG
2    SF   NYG
3    SF   NYG
4    SF   NYG
5    SF   NYG
6    SF   NYG
```

Comment: `.apply(pd.Series)` is easy to remember and type. Unfortunately, as stated in other answers, it is also very slow for large numbers of observations.
_If_ the index to be preserved is easily accessible, preservation using the DataFrame constructor approach is as simple as passing the `index` argument to the constructor, as seen in other answers. In the middle of a method chain, one workaround is to store an intermediate Series or DataFrame using an assignment expression (Python 3.8+) and then access the index from there.

Answer (score 23):

There seems to be a syntactically simpler way, and therefore easier to remember, as opposed to the proposed solutions. I'm assuming that the column is called 'meta' in a dataframe df:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['meta'].str.split().values.tolist())
```

Comment: This answer was helpful, and could be paired with this visual demonstration of the technique: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPKwm1XZjp8

Answer (score 17):

I would like to recommend a more efficient and Pythonic way.

First define the DataFrame as original post:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"teams": [["SF", "NYG"] for _ in range(7)]})
```

My solution:

```py
%%timeit
df['team1'], df['team2'] = zip(*list(df['teams'].values))
>> 761 µs ± 8.35 µs per loop
```

In comparison, the most upvoted solution:

```py
%%timeit
df[['team1','team2']] = pd.DataFrame(df.teams.tolist(), index=df.index)
df = pd.DataFrame(df['teams'].to_list(), columns=['team1','team2'])
>> 1.31 ms ± 11.2 µs per loop
```

My solution saves 40% time and is much shorter. The only thing you need to remember is how to unpack and reshape a two-dimension list by using `zip(*list)`.

Answer (score 12):

***List comprehension***

A simple implementation with list comprehension (my favorite)

```
df = pd.DataFrame([pd.Series(x) for x in df.teams])
df.columns = ['team_{}'.format(x+1) for x in df.columns]
```

Timing on output:

```
CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 0 ns, total: 0 ns
Wall time: 2.71 ms
```

Output:

```
team_1    team_2
0    SF    NYG
1    SF    NYG
2    SF    NYG
3    SF    NYG
4    SF    NYG
5    SF    NYG
6    SF    NYG
```

Answer (score 11):

The previous solutions didn't work for me since I have `nan` observations in my `dataframe`. In my case `df2[['team1','team2']] = pd.DataFrame(df2.teams.values.tolist(), index= df2.index)` yields:

```
object of type 'float' has no len()
```

I solve this using a list comprehension. Here is the replicable example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d1 = {'teams': [['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG'],
            ['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG']]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2.loc[2,'teams'] = np.nan
df2.loc[4,'teams'] = np.nan
df2
```

Output:

```
        teams
0   [SF, NYG]
1   [SF, NYG]
2   NaN
3   [SF, NYG]
4   NaN
5   [SF, NYG]
6   [SF, NYG]

df2['team1']=np.nan
df2['team2']=np.nan
```

Solving with a list comprehension,

```
for i in [0,1]:
    df2['team{}'.format(str(i+1))]=[k[i] if isinstance(k,list) else k for k in df2['teams']]

df2
```

yields:

```
    teams   team1   team2
0   [SF, NYG]   SF  NYG
1   [SF, NYG]   SF  NYG
2   NaN        NaN  NaN
3   [SF, NYG]   SF  NYG
4   NaN        NaN  NaN
5   [SF, NYG]   SF  NYG
6   [SF, NYG]   SF  NYG
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's another solution using [`df.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) and [`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> df['teams'].transform({'item1': itemgetter(0), 'item2': itemgetter(1)})

  team1 team2
0    SF   NYG
1    SF   NYG
2    SF   NYG
3    SF   NYG
4    SF   NYG
5    SF   NYG
6    SF   NYG
```

Which of course can be generalized as:

```
>>> indices = range(len(df['teams'][0]))

>>> df['teams'].transform({f'team{i+1}': itemgetter(i) for i in indices})

  team1 team2
0    SF   NYG
1    SF   NYG
2    SF   NYG
3    SF   NYG
4    SF   NYG
5    SF   NYG
6    SF   NYG
```

This approach has the added benefit of extracting the desired indices:

```
>>> df
                 teams
0  [SF, NYG, XYZ, ABC]
1  [SF, NYG, XYZ, ABC]
2  [SF, NYG, XYZ, ABC]
3  [SF, NYG, XYZ, ABC]
4  [SF, NYG, XYZ, ABC]
5  [SF, NYG, XYZ, ABC]
6  [SF, NYG, XYZ, ABC]

>>> indices = [0, 2]
>>> df['teams'].transform({f'team{i+1}': itemgetter(i) for i in indices})

  team1 team3
0    SF   XYZ
1    SF   XYZ
2    SF   XYZ
3    SF   XYZ
4    SF   XYZ
5    SF   XYZ
6    SF   XYZ
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on the previous answers, here is another solution which returns the same result as df2.teams.apply(pd.Series) with a much faster run time:

```
pd.DataFrame([{x: y for x, y in enumerate(item)} for item in df2['teams'].values.tolist()], index=df2.index)
```

Timings:

```
In [1]:
import pandas as pd
d1 = {'teams': [['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG'],
                ['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG'],['SF', 'NYG']]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2 = pd.concat([df2]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [2]: %timeit df2['teams'].apply(pd.Series)

8.27 s ± 2.73 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [3]: %timeit pd.DataFrame([{x: y for x, y in enumerate(item)} for item in df2['teams'].values.tolist()], index=df2.index)

35.4 ms ± 5.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone comes here to find a ready-made function, I wrote one.

- it finds all columns with lists and unfolds them, if `columns` are not specified;
- added columns are named as `column_name_0`, `column_name_1`, etc.;
- the columns order is preserved in final dataframe;
- if `strict=True`, it checks whether lists in a given column are of equal size.

Improvements and comments are appreciated.

```
def unfold_columns(df, columns=[], strict=False):
    assert isinstance(columns, list), "Columns should be a list of column names"
    if len(columns) == 0:
        columns = [
            column for column in df.columns 
            if df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, list)).all()[column]
        ]
    else:
        assert(all([(column in df.columns) for column in columns])), \
            "Not all given columns are found in df"
    columns_order = df.columns
    for column_name in columns:
        if df[column_name].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, list)).all():
            if strict:
                assert len(set(df[column_name].apply(lambda x: len(x)))) == 1, \
                    f"Lists in df['{column_name}'] are not of equal length"
            unfolded = pd.DataFrame(df[column_name].tolist())
            unfolded.columns = [f'{column_name}_{x}' for x in unfolded.columns]
            columns_order = [
                *columns_order[:list(columns_order).index(column_name)], 
                *unfolded.columns, 
                *columns_order[list(columns_order).index(column_name)+1:]
            ]
            df = df.join(unfolded).drop([column_name], axis=1)
    return df[columns_order]
```

Answer (score 1):

To *append* two new columns to the existing DataFrame:

```
df[['team1', 'team2']] = df["teams"].to_list()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use two times of apply to create new column 'team1' and 'team2' in your df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"teams": [["SF", "NYG"] for _ in range(7)]})
df["team1"]=df['teams'].apply(lambda x: x[0]  )
df["team2"]=df['teams'].apply(lambda x: x[1]  )
df
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R05A.png)

Comment: On dataframes that come from a groupby aggregation, this is the only method that worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing all the answers.
If you need just create new DataFrame with 2 columns

```
pd.DataFrame(df['teams'].tolist(), columns=['team1', 'team2'], index=df.index)
```

If you want to assign to the same df, you have several options.

1. The shortest

   df[['team1', 'team2']] = df['teams'].tolist()
2. The slowest (don't recommend, it might be 10x time slower or more without any advantages)

   df[['team1', 'team2']] = df['teams'].apply(pd.Series)
3. And the fastest for some reason (almost 2x faster than first).

   df['team1'], df['team2'] = zip(*df['teams'].tolist())

So I would recommend 1. If you really need speed, you can try 3, but that looks strange and the advantage may disappear in future versions.